# Autostart zookeeper instances

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, autostart

Helo,

I run a 2 machine setup with 5 Zookeeper instances on it. I know that normally minimum 3 machines are required to run a smal zookeeper quorum but for now I need to start with this 2 machines.  Now I want to create a script which autostarts all the zookeeper instances automaically in case of crashes or reboots. After all I want to build a stable environment which recovers automatically the following services:

solr
solrcloud
zookeeper
shardallocation

Does somebody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You require a good monitoring system for this. A simpler solution would be to write a cron jobs for all these boxes. These cron jobs would run curl or wget comands and check the output. If the output of the command is not as expected, restart your services. Also add the services to your startup with /etc/init.d so the services start with the reboot.